# Regular expression for deleting duplicated files

Tags: regex

I want delete all the duplicated files.

When a file is duplicated it's writing as this :

1. name.doc
2. name **(2)**.doc
3. name **(3)**.doc

... and I must only keep the file named **name.doc**. The other files must be deleted.

What it's the regular expresion to find all the files with (number) like the name **(2)**.doc?

A space character is present between the name file and the **(number)** notation.

Thanks for your help cause I don't find the good regular expression.

See you soon.

Comment: This question cannot be answered without an [edit] from you telling us what your operating system is, and in what program you want to use the regular expressions.

Comment: He could be using Everything (a program to search for files, that allows for using regular expressions).

Answer (score 0):

There are much better ways than using regex to find duplicate files, but to answer your question:

```
/.*\ \(\d*\)\.[A-za-z]*/g
```

What it matches:

```
.         any character except newline
*         any number of the previous character
\ \(\d*\) first a space, then a (, then any digit, then a )
\.        dot
[A-za-z]* any number of letters (for the extension)
```

You can [test things out here](http://regexr.com/).

A good way of testing is using CMD to create a text file with all the file names of a folder, then pasting those in the site I mentioned. You can do this by opening CMD, moving to a folder with lots of copies (by using `cd` folder name to navigate), then typing `dir > filenames.txt`.

You'll find a file called `filenames.txt` in the folder, from wich you can copy all filenames to regexr.com so you can see which files will be matched by the regex I provided.